# How to add methods from SQLite DB class in fragment of Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have an insert,update,read method in helperclass,how can I use in the following class?

Im not very used to kotlin  but id like to now how can we insert the DB methods and integrate it with the code below

After adding a  checkfield method ive been receiving an error when i add it in the onclicklistner

package com.google.samples.apps.topeka.fragment

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.support.v4.util.Pair
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat
import android.support.v4.view.animation.FastOutSlowInInterpolator
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.transition.Transition
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.adapter.AvatarAdapter
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.base.R
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.ActivityLaunchHelper
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.ApiLevelHelper
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.DefaultLogin
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.TAG
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.TransitionHelper
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.isLoggedIn
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.login
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.onLayoutChange
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.helper.onSmartLockResult
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.model.Avatar
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.model.Player
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.persistence.TopekaDatabaseHelper
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.widget.TextWatcherAdapter
import com.google.samples.apps.topeka.widget.TransitionListenerAdapter

/**
 * Enable selection of an [Avatar] and user name.
 */
class SignInFragment : Fragment() {

    private var firstNameView: EditText? = null
    private var lastInitialView: EditText? = null
    private var doneFab: FloatingActionButton? = null
    private var avatarGrid: GridView? = null

    private val edit by lazy { arguments?.getBoolean(ARG_EDIT, false) ?: false }


    private var selectedAvatarView: View? = null
    private var player: Player? = null
    private var selectedAvatar: Avatar? = null

    var a = TopekaDatabaseHelper.getInstance(this.requireContext())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            val avatarIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_SELECTED_AVATAR_INDEX)
            if (avatarIndex != GridView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                selectedAvatar = Avatar.values()[avatarIndex]
            }
        }



        activity?.run {
            if (isLoggedIn()) {
                navigateToCategoryActivity()
            } else {
                login.loginPlayer(this, ::onSuccessfulLogin)
            }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    /**
     * Called when logged in successfully.
     */
    private fun onSuccessfulLogin(player: Player) {
        if (login != DefaultLogin) return
        this.player = player
        if (edit) {
            with(player) {
                firstNameView?.setText(player.firstName)
                lastInitialView?.run {
                    setText(player.lastInitial)
                    requestFocus()
                    setSelection(length())
                }
                this@SignInFragment.player = player.also {
                    if (activity != null)
                        login.savePlayer(activity!!, this, { selectAvatar(it.avatar!!) })
                }
            }
        } else {
            navigateToCategoryActivity()
        }
    }



    private fun navigateToCategoryActivity() {
        activity?.run {
            ActivityLaunchHelper.launchCategorySelection(this)
            supportFinishAfterTransition()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        activity?.onSmartLockResult(
                requestCode,
                resultCode,
                data,
                success = {
                    player = it
                    initContents()
                    navigateToCategoryActivity()
                },
                failure = {
                    activity?.run {
                        login.loginPlayer(this, ::onSuccessfulLogin)
                    }
                }
        )
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, container, false)


        val Button =
        contentView.onLayoutChange {
            avatarGrid?.apply {
                adapter = AvatarAdapter(activity!!)
                onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, view, position, _ ->
                    selectedAvatarView = view
                    selectedAvatar = Avatar.values()[position]
                    // showing the floating action button if input data is valid
                    showFab()
                }
                numColumns = calculateSpanCount()
                selectedAvatar?.run { selectAvatar(this) }



            }
        }
        return contentView
    }

    /**
     * Calculates spans for avatars dynamically.

     * @return The recommended amount of columns.
     */
    private fun calculateSpanCount(): Int {
        val avatarSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.size_fab)
        val avatarPadding = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing_double)
        return (avatarGrid?.width ?: 0) / (avatarSize + avatarPadding)
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.putInt(KEY_SELECTED_AVATAR_INDEX, (avatarGrid?.checkedItemPosition ?: 0))
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        firstNameView = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.first_name)
        lastInitialView = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.last_initial)
        doneFab = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.done)
        avatarGrid = view.findViewById<GridView>(R.id.avatars)

        if (edit || (player != null && player!!.valid())) {
            initContentViews()
            initContents()
        }
        hideEmptyView()
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun hideEmptyView() {
        view?.run {
            findViewById<View>(R.id.empty).visibility = View.GONE
            findViewById<View>(R.id.content).visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }



    private fun initContentViews() {
        val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher by TextWatcherAdapter {

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                // hiding the floating action button if text is empty
                if (s.isEmpty()) {
                    doneFab?.hide()
                }
            }

            // showing the floating action button if avatar is selected and input data is valid
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                if (isAvatarSelected() && isInputDataValid()) doneFab?.show()
            }
        }

        firstNameView?.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        lastInitialView?.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        doneFab?.setOnClickListener {
            if (it.id == R.id.done) {
                var first = firstNameView?.text?.toString()
                var last = lastInitialView?.text?.toString()

                //
                try {
                    a.adduser(first,last,"string")

                }
                catch (e:Exception) {
                    // handler
                }



                activity?.run {
                    val toSave = player?.apply {
                        // either update the existing player object




                        firstName = first
                        lastInitial = last
                        avatar = selectedAvatar

                        a.adduser(first,last,avatar.toString())
                    } ?: Player(first, last, selectedAvatar) /* or create a new one */

                    login.savePlayer(this, toSave) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Saving login info successful.")
                    }
                }
            }
            removeDoneFab {
                performSignInWithTransition(selectedAvatarView
                        ?: avatarGrid?.getChildAt(selectedAvatar!!.ordinal))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun removeDoneFab(endAction: () -> Unit) {
        ViewCompat.animate(doneFab)
                .scaleX(0f)
                .scaleY(0f)
                .setInterpolator(FastOutSlowInInterpolator())
                .withEndAction(endAction)
                .start()
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun performSignInWithTransition(v: View? = null) {
        if (v == null || ApiLevelHelper.isLowerThan(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)) {
            // Don't run a transition if the passed view is null
            activity?.run {
                navigateToCategoryActivity()
            }
            return
        }

        if (ApiLevelHelper.isAtLeast(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)) {
            activity?.run {
                window.sharedElementExitTransition.addListener(object :
                        Transition.TransitionListener by TransitionListenerAdapter {
                    override fun onTransitionEnd(transition: Transition) {
                        finish()
                    }
                })

                val pairs = TransitionHelper.createSafeTransitionParticipants(this, true,
                        Pair(v, getString(R.string.transition_avatar)))
                val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, *pairs)
                ActivityLaunchHelper.launchCategorySelection(this, options)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initContents() {
        player?.run {
            valid().let {
                firstNameView?.setText(firstName)
                lastInitialView?.setText(lastInitial)
                avatar?.run { selectAvatar(this) }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isAvatarSelected() = selectedAvatarView != null || selectedAvatar != null

    private fun selectAvatar(avatar: Avatar) {
        selectedAvatar = avatar
        avatarGrid?.run {
            requestFocusFromTouch()
            setItemChecked(avatar.ordinal, true)
        }
        showFab()
    }

    private fun showFab() {
        if (isInputDataValid()) doneFab?.show()
    }

    private fun isInputDataValid() =
            firstNameView?.text?.isNotEmpty() == true &&
                    lastInitialView?.text?.isNotEmpty() == true &&
                    selectedAvatar != null

    companion object {

        private const val ARG_EDIT = "EDIT"
        private const val KEY_SELECTED_AVATAR_INDEX = "selectedAvatarIndex"

        fun newInstance(edit: Boolean = false): SignInFragment {
            return SignInFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putBoolean(ARG_EDIT, edit)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```